# Docker args with whitespaces from variable. How to use it>

Tags: linux, bash, docker, loops, continuous-integration

I have searched the answer at stackoverflow(and google too) for 3 hours and I didnt find correct solution.

In my CI a need to dynamicly add docker build arguments. And I need to use it from env variables.

I have a string with docker arg:
`DOCKER_ARGS="CURL_ARGS='-k https://example.invalid/'|ARG2=As|ARG3=asdas"`

In my *.sh I wrote some code:

```sh
DOCKER_ARGS="CURL_ARGS='-k https://example.invalid/'|ARG2=As|ARG3=asdas"
if [ ! -z "$DOCKER_ARGS" ]; then 
    ARG_LIST=()
    while read -d"|" ARG || [[ -n "$ARG" ]];
    do 
    ARG_LIST+=("--build-arg $ARG")
    done <<<$DOCKER_ARGS
fi
docker build -t test . ${ARG_LIST[@]}
```

And when I use `echo ${ARG_LIST[@]}`, I receive correct result:

```
--build-arg CURL_ARGS='-k https://example.invalid/' --build-arg ARG2=As --build-arg ARG3=asdas
```

But when I use `docker build -t test . ${ARG_LIST[@]}` it gives me an error:

"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.

And if I use echo for command:

`echo "docker build -t test . ${ARG_LIST[@]}"` - I had correct result

I expect that will works as:

`docker build -t image:tag . --build-arg CURL_ARGS='-k https://example.invalid/' --build-arg ARG2=As --build-arg ARG3=asdas`

Comment: Check your scripts with http://shellcheck.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems with your script.

> ```
> DOCKER_ARGS="CURL_ARGS='-k https://example.invalid/'|ARG2=As|ARG3=asdas"
> ```

With current handling `CURL_ARGS` will be set to `'-k https://example.invalid/'` **including the quotes**. Either remove the quotes from the input, or write your own un-quoting removal routine.

> ```
> read -d"|" ARG
> ```

Removes trailing and leading whitespaces from input because of `IFS` and interprets missing slash sequences because or missing `-r`.

> ```
> ARG_LIST+=("--build-arg $ARG")
> ```

Assigns a **single** element with the value `--build-arg $ARG` to the array. You would have to split later on the space between `build-arg` and `$ARG`. Instead assign **two** elements - one for `--build-arg` and the other for `$ARG`.

A better script might look like the following:

```
docker_args="CURL_ARGS=-k https://example.invalid/|ARG2=As|ARG3=asdas"
arg_list=()
if [[ -n "$docker_args" ]]; then 
    # split input on `|` 
    # Potentially use readarray to handle newlines
    IFS='|' read -r -a args <<<"$docker_args"
    # Add --built-arg to arrays
    for arg in "${args[@]}"; do
        # Proper quoting
        arg_list+=(--build-arg "$arg")
    done
fi
#                      proper quoting
docker build -t test . "${arg_list[@]}"
```

Check your scripts with http://shellcheck.net . Re-research how quoting works in shell and to use bash arrays. Prefer to use lower case variable names.

Comment: Thanks lot for the answer! It works good!